# How to update range_color in Plotly Express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am using plotly express and I want to display some data:

```
import plotly.express as px
dfx = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(dfx, 
                 x='total_bill', y='tip', 
                 color='size', 
                 template='plotly_dark', 
                 range_color=[2,4])
```

My goal is to update the range color after it has been defined.

I tried something like this:

```
fig.update_layout(range_color=[3,6])

ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'range'
```

but without success.

Are you aware of what I need to write in order to update the range color values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the range of the color bar, you would change the maximum and minimum values of the color axis. This is different from the description of the graph settings, which can be found in `fig.layout`.

```
import plotly.express as px
dfx = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(dfx, 
                 x='total_bill', y='tip', 
                 color='size', 
                 template='plotly_dark', 
                 range_color=[2,4])

fig.update_layout(coloraxis=dict(cmax=6, cmin=3))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know what is the difference with the "colorscale" option provided by the answer below?

Comment: The [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#continuous-color-concepts) explains that the color axis connects the color scale, color range, and color bar to the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use range_color in the px.scatter function

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df,
   x="sepal_width",
   y="sepal_length",
   color="sepal_length",
   color_continuous_scale=["red",
   "green", "blue"])
fig.show()
```

Here is a link to the documentation [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/)

You can also look here at fig.update_coloraxes

[update coloraxes](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/)

Also just found this in the documentation for `update_layout`

`fig.update_layout(colorscale=dict(...))`

[update colorscale](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-colorscale)

Comment: thanks for the reply but my goal is to have the range_color updated outside of the function.

Comment: Updated the answer. See if that works. Does your use case require it to be updated outside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know what is the difference with the "coloraxis" option provided by the answer above?